# Is "How much more miserable should he be?" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, expressions

I know it is safe to say

> "How miserable should he be?"

but I wonder I can add much/more/e.t.c in the sentece to
emphasize the level of misery.

Such as

> how much miserable should he be?

or

> how much more miserable should he be?

Thank you!

Comment: The sentence "How miserable should he be?" is grammatically correct, but I'm not sure it means exactly what you seem to think it means.  It means something like "He should be miserable.  Exactly how much should he be miserable?" It's like "How big a cake should I bake?"  Is that what you're trying to say?

Comment: I wanted to ask " how much more hardships(that make him miserable) does he have to go through?" but in a short sentence.

Comment: Maybe "How much more misery should he face?" As used here, see: [*face*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/face): "4. *verb* - If you **face or are faced** with something difficult or unpleasant, or if it **faces** you, it is going to affect you and you have to deal with it." In this example, you can use *much* or *much more* to intensify.

Comment: With *miserable*, you can use only "How miserable" and "How much more miserable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how much miserable should he be?

is not valid English.

> how much more miserable should he be?

is valid and, lacking context, sounds pretty similar to the original sentence.